# not able to access virtual machine centos from other computers

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

I have setup apache on centos 7 vm inside ubuntu host. I can access the webserver my giving ip of guest on the host fine. But, If I try to access it from another computer on the  network , it does not work. I cannot even ping to my guest vm ip from other computers.there is no firewall in centos and no selinux.please advise.I am using KVM

Answer (score 0):

Check your route

apache2 restrictions

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-??

when you say you can access do you mean when on the host you can access the host? if this is the case can you ping out? alot of info is missing to determine what is wrong

if it is and I am guessing the configuration on the network device make sure to systemctl restart network when you are done